# how to insert the multiple array rows in the database?

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

i am working on dynamic array i need to insert these array in the database.when i insert dynamic array into the database instead of inserting all rows it only inserting one row in the database.

below is the array that contain result

```
$asma[]=GA::select($ga->population,'total',3);
```

below is code for inserting multiple array in database table `ga`

```
<?php 
//code not tested check it

//Logic is changed instead of for looping many times
$data = array();

$j = 0;

foreach($asma as $key => $value)
{
$i = 0;

foreach ( $value as $ind => $hObject )
{
    if($i==0)
    {
        $data[$j]['fe'] = mysql_escape_string($hObject->Voltage);

    }else{

        $data[$j]['fe'.$i] = mysql_escape_string($hObject->Voltage);
    }

    $i++;

    $data[$j]['fe'.$i] = mysql_escape_string($hObject->Duration);
    $i++;

    $data[$j]['fe'.$i] = mysql_escape_string($hObject->Number);
    $i++;

}

$j++;

}// endforeach

//multiple array
 foreach($data as $array)
 {


 //unique array
//$array3 = array_merge($Voltage,$Duration,$Number);

$fields = implode(',',array_keys($array));

//if you want append any new field append it
$fields .= ','.'timestamp,username';

$vals = "'".implode("','",array_values($array))."'";

//if you want append any new values append it
$vals .= ",'".time()."','".$login_session."'";


$q = "INSERT INTO ga (".$fields.") VALUES(".$vals.")";

$result = mysql_query($q);
if ( ! $result ) {
    die( 'Insert failed ' . mysql_errno() . ' ' . mysql_error() );
}
 }
```

whenever user enter 3 then after computation result will store in array `asma` after store result will store in table `ga` that should be three rows but only one row insert in the table and display instead of three same in case the user enter any value in the text box.

Comment: Asked and answered many many times, please use the search

Comment: @BobDavies help me in this  i asked first time

Comment: plz ppl help me in this

Comment: please don't use mysql.. it is deprecated.. use instead PDO or mysqli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean, i think is an insert statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO `ga` (`field1`, `field2`, `field3`, `etc`)
VALUES (value11, value21, value31, more_values1),
    (value12, value22, value32, more_values2),
    (value13, value23, value33, more_values3)
```

So you should use your `foreach` cycle to create the values statement.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `ga` (`voltage`, `duration`, `number`, `timestamp`, `username`) VALUES ";

$values = "";
foreach ($asma as $row) {
    $values .= ($values != "" ? "," : "") . "(" .
            "'" . $row['voltage'] . "', " .
            "'" . $row['voltage'] . "', " .
            "'" . $row['number'] . "', " .
            "'" . time() . "', " .
            "'" . $login_session . "'" .
            "),";
}

$sql .= substr($values, 0, -1) . ";";
```

Comment: should i used both insert statement

Comment: $sql is the insert statement.
In the end it will look like the first example i gave.

Comment: shoukd i remove my all previous code which i pasted n enters your or can u tell where should i plsce in the code

Comment: I can't answer that, i don't know what you want to do. I just gave an example to create a multi row INSERT. Better don't remove, just comment it.

Comment: What happens? What appears on the screen? Does it give any error? you should try to "echo $sql" after it is built. I've notice some failures on  the code i wrote. i will edit it.